# Append to inner list level of nested list

Tags: r, list, nested, append

Ok so I need to programmatically combine two nested lists in a particular way. Hard to explain so easiest thing is to give a toy model. Suppose I have two nested lists as follows:

```
a <- list(101:110, 201:210)
b <- list(111:120, 211:220)
d <- list(311:320, 311:320)
nestlist1 <- list(a, b)
nestlist2 <- list(d)
```

The lists look like this:

```
> nestlist1
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110

[[1]][[2]]
 [1] 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1] 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120

[[2]][[2]]
 [1] 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220


> nestlist2
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320

[[1]][[2]]
 [1] 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320
```

Given the two nested lists above, how do I write code (base R or purrr) to make the lists look like this:

```
 > wantedlist
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110

[[1]][[2]]
 [1] 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210

[[1]][[3]]
 [1] 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1] 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120

[[2]][[2]]
 [1] 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220

[[2]][[3]]
 [1] 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` and then just create a function to append a list:

```
a <- list(101:110, 201:210)
b <- list(111:120, 211:220)
d <- list(311:320, 311:320)

nestlist1 <- list(a, b)
nestlist2 <- list(d)

wantedlist <- list()
append_list <- function(l1, l2) c(l1, list(l2))
Map(f = append_list, nestlist1, unlist(nestlist2, recursive = FALSE))

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110

[[1]][[2]]
 [1] 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210

[[1]][[3]]
 [1] 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1] 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120

[[2]][[2]]
 [1] 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220

[[2]][[3]]
 [1] 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320
```

Comment: My toy might be a bit too simple compared to my application but I can probably develop it from this. Thanks for your help